# How is the word "ne" used in sentences?

Tags: grammaire, sens

When I read French books, this word makes me confused all the times. Its meaning varies up on a sentence, sometimes refers to *only*, however, sometimes means *not*.

In my opinion, if it's used without *pas*, it always means “only”, however, it means negation when it's used with *pas`*.

For example,

> Il ne contient qu'un seul amas riche de galaxies

→ It contains only one cluster of galaxies

> Il ne contient pas d'argent.

→ He doesn't have money.

Nevertheless,

> On ne peut avoir de dépendance.

→ We cannot have dependence !!

Could you explain it along with the examples? I want to understand it clearly in order to read and write French.

Comment: [This answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/7452/79) of mine on another question might be of interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Ne** as a part of double negation:

- ne ... pas
- ne ... aucun
- ne ... jamais
- ne ... plus
- ne ... rien
- ne ... personne

These ways of negation are often mutually exclusive, for example:

> **Ne ... pas** cannot be used with **aucun**, **jamais**, or **personne**.
>
> - Wrong: Je n'ai pas aucun ami.
> - Right: Je n'ai aucun ami. *I have no friends.*

- **ne ... que** means "only"
- **ne ... pas que** means "not only"

> - Je ne regrette qu'une chose. *I regret only one thing.*
> - Je ne regrette pas qu'une chose. *I don't regret only one thing.*

- **ne** in formal French:

> *Cesser*, *oser*, and *pouvoir* don't need **pas**:
>
> - Elle ne peut venir avec nous. *She can't come with us.*

"On ne peut avoir de dépendance" is exactly this case.

Source of examples:

- [French Double Negatives ~ Négation double](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_double.htm)
- [French Literary Ne - Formal French](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/negation_form_3.htm)

Other links you might find useful: [1](http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/only.htm), 
[2](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/neg3.html), [3](http://www.lepointdufle.net/p/negation.htm#.UsPaC4lhic0)

Answer (score 4):

These explanations are simplified from Grevisse's *Le Bon Usage*, 14th ed. §§1010-1026

Historically, *ne* was the only expression of the negation, it functioned somewhat like *not* in that regard. With time, what were originally emphatic (*pas* being the most common) or additional adverbs (*rien*, *jamais*) etc. came to become required, leading to ne+pas or another adverb being the normal expression of negation (ironically in modern colloquial French, *ne* is now dropped instead).

The original usage  remains generally possible, however, as you note in your last example (and *pouvoir* is in fact one of the verbs that most naturally allows the construction), but is generally associated with a rather literary or elevated style, or with a limited number of expressions where it is obligatory, such as *n'importe qui*, *Il ne boit ni ne mange*, *je ne sais que faire* etc.

Besides the complex issue of what are known as *ne explétifs* (§§1023-4), where the *ne* has little to no semantic connection to negation, Grevisse (§1018) freely admits that *ne que* is an oddity. But it is one with a prestigious pedigree, since it traces right back to the Latin *non aliud quam*, which actually expressed that the two items thus connected were not different, hence, the same. This eventually evolved (though Grevisse doesn't detail the semantic evolution) into a sort of "negated negative", hence "only".

Answer (score 0):

I once stumbled upon the wiki article for [Jespersen’s Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jespersen's_Cycle) which immediately helped me really grok the negation (and confirm my suspicions that *ne* is the “true” particle for negation).

About *ne que*: I know read it as “nothing but”. Actually, as I’m German I’m reading it as “nichts als” which is how Germans say “nothing but” – that works quite well because “als” literally means “than” in English or “que” in French and is used as the particle in comparative. So that’s how *ne que* means “only” – maybe no *inherit* explanation, but it’s actually not that unfamiliar.

In the same vein, *ne … aucun*, *ne … plus* and almost all other negations make a lot more sense.