# Le sens de « Personne ne l'a pas fait » ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, double-négation

Je me demande ce que « Personne ne l'a pas fait » veut dire: « tout le monde l'a fait » ou « il n'y a pas de gens qui l'ont fait » ?

Comment: Le deuxième ne veut rien dire du tout. Quand au premier, c'est la bonne réponse.

Comment: @Bregalad Pourquoi ne pas en faire une réponse en précisant le fonctionnement de la double négation *personne/ne pas*, et pourquoi la dernière formule est  fausse car elle retire la seconde négation originelle ?

Comment: Evidemment, avec l'édit mon commentaire n'est plus valable puisque les propositions changes. Et de toutes façons je n'en ai aucune idée du fonctionnement de la double négations, je suis francophone, pas prof de français...

Comment: Voir aussi [négation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/n%C3%A9gation): _Toute proposition équivaut à la négation de sa négation._ La première de la deuxième ici. Mais il s'agit de logique et non pas de la langue, à mon avis.

Comment: Oui, surtout que la double négation se retrouve dans bien d'autres langages tel que l'anglais (avec un joli exemple, "I didn't do nothing", qui est  du mauvais anglais...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ne* can combine with many other negation words as explained in [this anwser](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7452/79), and it will form a single negation. Here is an extreme example with 5 surrounding negation words:

> *Personne* **ne** dit *plus* *jamais* *rien* à *personne*.

That is: “**no**body ever says anything to anyone else anymore.”

However *pas* cannot normally be part of a larger combination of surrounding words. If you turn the *plus* into a *pas*:

> *Personne* **ne** dit **pas** *jamais* *rien* à *personne*.

The sentence becomes ungrammatical and utterly incomprehensible in this case. People may try to interpret it as a double negation, but it is not clear how. It could however sometimes be used in conversation to disagree with someone who previously said “Personne ne dit jamais rien à personne”. In this case it would be interpreted as “You're wrong. It is **not** the case that nobody ever says anything to anyone else.

Your example,

> *Personne* **ne** l'a **pas** fait.

sounds a bit weird because it's similarly ungrammatical. Though people can understand it as a different kind of cancelling double-negation: “**no**body did **not** do it”, which sounds similarly weird but is easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

« Personne ne l'a pas fait » veut dire « tout le monde l'a fait ».

Comment: Disons plutôt que les expressions sont équivalentes sur le plan logique. En revanche, en France métropolitaine on entendra presque jamais la première variante (avec la double négation). Je précise le lieu car il me semble qu'au Québec on utilise un peu différemment les négations avec le terme *personne*, à confirmer par un habitant de la Belle Province.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Pas [formellement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2893). Peut-être à l'oral familier un truc comme « Y a pas personne icitte » vs. « Y a personne icitte » - le sens est identifque; je spécule à l'effet que comme on a sublimé le _ne_, alors on a un réflexe d'ajouter _pas_ ... bancal avec ou sans, mais fonctionnel.

Answer (score 0):

En maths, la négation de "pour tout x, on a x > y" par exemple, c'est "il existe **un** x tel que x < y".
Le raisonnement se tient à l'identique ici, du coup :

- "Tout le monde l'a fait" deviendra "Il y a au moins une personne qui ne l'a pas fait"
- "Il n'y a pas de gens qui l'a fait" (dit autrement, "Personne ne l'a fait") deviendra "Au moins une personne l'a fait".