# Construct with "personne" and "pas"

Tags: grammaire, négation, oral

Would "*No one has arrived*" be "*personne n'est pas arrivé*" or "*personne n'est arrivé*"? In which case will the "*pas*" absorbed by personne as in "*Personne ne me connaît ici*"? Or "*personne*" never goes with "*pas*" because it already carry/equivalent to a negative meaning, such as "*Je ne connais personne ici*"?

Google translate gives me "*personne n'a arrivés*". If it is correct, why "*n'a arrivés*" and not "*n'est arrivés*", and why plural "*arrivés*" for "*personne*"? I thought it has a singular meaning.

Comment: You are right, google is wrong :) You are also right about the "pas"... The probel is that google misread "no one", so he translate the 2 groups "no one has" and "arrived"... he doesn't understand that the verb is "has arrived"

Comment: This may be of interest: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7452

Comment: Follow-up question by the same user: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14426/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct translation is indeed

> Personne n'est arrivé

And as you correctly deducted, "personne" already has a negative meaning so you shouldn't combine it with "pas" (but keeping the `ne` or in this case `n'`). If you do so, it's called a `double négation`. Double negations are usually tricky and therefore used very rarely and most of the time to induct confusion.

As in mathematics, double negation turns out to be positive.

> Personne n'est pas arrivé (Nobody hasn't arrived)

means

> Tout le monde est arrivé (Everybody has arrived)

or, if you want to use a plural ("Tout le monde" having a singular meaning being seen as one whole group)

> Toutes les personnes sont arrivées (All the people have arrived)

where you should be careful not to mix up `la personne/les personnes` the noun , meaning "the people" and `personne` the pronoun meaning "nobody".

The Google translation you mention is indeed completely wrong but would be understood if ever you express it that way.

When refering to things instead of people, `rien` (nothing) should be used instead of `personne` (nobody). The grammatical use would be almost the same, at least regarding negation :

> Tu n'as rien compris

... no "pas" in this sentence, `rien` conveying negative meaning.

Note that in this case `rien` comes between auxialiary and verb. "Tu n'as compris rien" isn't correct. I couldn't give a technical explanation about why though... I think your confusion might come from the fact `rien` is actually translated differently in English depending you're speaking positively or negatively. Actually as I think about it I guess it's more correct in English too to use "not ... anything" than just "nothing". I already heard sentences like "I didn't do nothing", but it's not how I was taught English...

Comment: Thanks Laurent. Will _rien_ behaves similarly as personne ? "Tu n'as rien fait", "Rien ne s'est fait"(nothing has been done) and not "rien ne s'est pas fait". Also, what is the difference between "Tu n'as rien compris" and "Tu n'as compris rien"?

Comment: I edited my answer to include "rien"

Comment: Minor remark: I am OK with the double negation, but the opposite of "_personne_" is not "_tout le monde_", it is "_quelqu'un_". Same as with "_Tout le monde n'est pas arrivé_": some are here, but not everyone yet.

Comment: If _personne_ has absored the negation, why do we still need _ne_ as negation ? As in english _nobody has arrived_ , _nobody_ carries the whole negation meaning, the verb is in affirmative form.

Comment: @Chop : I agree, although in this case with double negation I'm uite sure it's correct, in most cases "some people" or "someone" is enough to tell the contrary and "evrybody" is just the exception, when all of these "someone" have arrived.

Comment: @Kenny : you're right, I will add this precision to my answer.

Comment: @Laurent : I have updated my question with another point. Thanks.

Comment: @Kenny > please ask a different question and if you wish put a reference to this one, but I don't think this is related in any way.Your additional interrogation is about tenses and not the use of "Personne" and should then be part of another question. Note that not all tenses are "translatable" directly to French; Without further context, it can often be discussed whether to use or not a continuous tense for example. "Je bois de la vodka" could be translated to "I'm drinking vodka" (=> right now) or "I drink Vodka" (=> usually; I've nothing against vodka)

Answer (score 2):

> Would "No one has arrived" be "personne n'est pas arrivé" or "personne
>   n'est arrivé"?

*No one has arrived* is translated with *Personne n'est arrivé*.

---

> In which case will the "pas" absorbed by personne as in "Personne ne
>   me connaît ici"? Or "personne" never goes with "pas" because it
>   already carry/equivalent to a negative meaning, such as "Je ne connais
>   personne ici"?

The word *personne* (in French) is twofold. In your question the nature of *personne* is the second in the list:

- It can be a noun. The translation in English is *person*. Its gender is feminine. And more than one plural exist: *people*/*persons*
- It can be a *negative [indefinite pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun)*. Its translation is *anyone*/*anybody*/*somebody*/*someone* if used without *ne* (negation); if used with *ne* (negation) its translation is *nobody*. Its gender is masculine.

*personne* (indefinite pronoun) in the sense of *nobody* is very common.

*personne* (indefinite pronoun)  with the meaning of *anybody*/*anyone*/*somebody*/*someone* is less common. Examples:

- *faire quelque chose comme/mieux que personne* ~= *to do something better than anyone/anybody (else)*
- *sans personne pour m'aider* ~= *without anyone ou anybody to help me*
- *personne de blessé?* ~= *anyone ou anybody hurt?*

You don't use *personne* and *pas* together to emphasize a stronger negation for example.  I have never seen that in a sentence.

Laurent gave a good example of the usage of double negation in his answer (excellent mention).

---

> Google translate gives me "personne n'a arrivés". If it is correct,
>   why "n'a arrivés" and not "n'est arrivés", and why plural "arrivés"
>   for "personne"? I thought it has a singular meaning.

Google Translate uses probability theory and statistics. The translations are fallible at times, not like a dictionary for example. I suggest not to rely on Google Translate and use dictionaries or site like this one.

Comment: Thanks ;). No I don't count on Google translate for sure. I use it mostly for orthography purpose, to correct accents or when I am sure 80-90% and need some further help.

Comment: I can't think of an example where "Personne" would be used without "ne" and translated to "anyone/anybody/somebody/someone". For those I would rather use French word "Quelqu'un".

Comment: I updated my answer with some examples

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I didn't think about these. "Quiconque/qui que ce soit" might also be a good fit though, but your examples are indeed more usual.