# Why is "Personne n'arrivait" using passé composé and not imparfait?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

I would like to extend further [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/construct-with-personne-and-pas/14418?noredirect=1#comment27453_14418)

*No one has arrived* in English would translate to *Personne n'est arrivé* in French.

In English we would use present perfect tense because it signifies something starting in the past and still going on to the present: no one arrived and they are still not here at the moment and this will continue on to the future.

In French it would be *Personne n'est arrivé* which to me is something happened once and complete in the past, such as *Je suis rentré/sorti*, *Il m'a quitté*. Why are we using it here for *No one has arrived*. For me if something started in the pass and continue to the present, I would think of *imparfait* : *"Personne n'arrivait"*. So why are we not using it here and what would it mean if I say *"Personne n'arrivait"*?

Comment: the *imparfait* doesn't continue in the future. It just says it is a long action, and not a brief one. To do that, you could add Personne n'est **encore** arrivé, saying it is possible for someone to *arrive* now

Comment: But does it does mean something started in the past and continue to now, the moment we are making the sentence ?

Comment: Yes it does, but it also slightly implies you're expecting someone to arrive

Comment: I am asking myself because what you explain would fit perfectly into _present perfect_ tense in English. In present perfect, I am also expecting someone to arrive. It would mean a continuous event: something _started_ in the past, _continue_ to the present and has not changed yet, so it will _likely_ continue into the future. For example, _I have lived in France for 2 years_.

Comment: That's it, you can then upvote / accept @LaurentS.' answer, since he suggests the same thing ;)

Comment: "Personne n'arrivait" carries the same meaning as the English phrase "No one was arriving". You might say "Personne n'arrivait, donc je suis parti".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think my answer in the previous post might have been slightly incorrect in English and therefore confusing you. I personally don't make a real difference between "Nobody arrived" and "Nobody has arrived", and I think that's were I'm wrong. Actually, the real meaning of "Personne n'est arrivé" depends of the context.

**You could be telling a story that happened in the past :**

> J'attendais mes amis mais personne n'est arrivé.

-> The action was in the past and is finished, nobody did ever arrive. We use "imparafait" because it's an action that spans over time. I would translate this to :

> I was waiting for my friends but nobody (ever) arrived

but I guess it could be translated to

> I waited for my friends but nobody (ever) arrived

I couldn't tell if both translations have the exact same meaning though, I would maybe mistakenly use either one or the other without further thinking.

**You could also be telling about something happening now :**

> J'attends mes amis mais personne n'est (encore) arrivé.

-> The action is in the present, I'm still waiting, and nobody arrived hitherto (and if anyone had arrived, that would have been in the past from now, so we use "passé composé"). I would translate this to :

> I'm waiting for my friends but nobody arrived (yet)

I'm no translator nor French or English expert, but I think tenses in French and English just don't always have a direct translation and that may lead to some confusion. French doesn't have "continuous" tenses for example. Taking my example from previous question remark :

> Je bois de la vodka

could be translated to "I'm drinking vodka" (=> right now) or "I drink Vodka" (=> usually; I've nothing against vodka as a general matter)

As of the difference between various past tenses in French, I think those 2 schemas combined summarize it well :

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is indeed no easy correspondance map for tenses in English and French. Present perfect and _passé composé_ are not equivalent. There are clear rules (so far as rules requiring judgement can be clear) about when to use present perfect (present recap of something started in the past, to wrap it up). There are basic rules for _passé simple_ and _imparfait_ in literary writing. I am not aware of rules for _passé composé_ in French. @LaurentS. I think the _yet_ implies present perfect: "nobody **has** arrived (yet)".

Comment: I agree with your last remark, the yet is actually providing the context that the action is still going on and we expect current situation to change in the future. Now i remember my English lessons from a long time ago, I also recall a lot of discussions on that subject with the teacher when translating isolated sentences...

Comment: _Nobody has arrived (yet)_ would mean something commenced in the past and continue til the present, as in _I am waiting and my friend has not arrived yet_ . This would be _present perfect_, which I tend to map to _imparfait_. Simple past, which I tend to map to French's _passé composé_, describes something happened and terminated in the past, as in we are telling a thing happening in the past _Last week I waited for you but you did not arrive_. Do _passé composé_ and _imparfait_ not mean as I have described ? And what would _personne n'arrivait_ mean ?

Comment: Perhaps another example that describes better what I mean than _arrive_ . _I have lived in France for 2 years_ , and I am still living now, and likely continue into the future. _I lived 2 years in France, but now I no longer do_.

Comment: Once a teacher told me that passé simple is mostly only used in formal writing now. And from your diagram it looks like it is equivalent to the passé composé : an action happening for a brief time in the past. Is it correct?

Comment: There is nuance between _I was waiting for my friends but nobody arrived_ and _I waited for my friends, nobody arrived_ . The first tends to be used when you mention something continuous happening when something else _jumped in_ , as in _I was waiting for you when it started raining_ .The second does not carry that sense, it is a general story-telling of something happening in the past, without emphasizing the long duration nor some interruption.To me the more correct would be _I waited but nobody arrived_ because the second did not happen. But _I was waiting at the station when he passed by_

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly why this is.
But

> Personne n'est arrivé

is an observation at point T in time. Nobody is there.

> Personne n'arrivait

It gives the idea of continuously observing the situation. Nobody was coming. There is the feeling of waiting for it to happen. The imparfait has this notion of continuity.
Well, at least in my mind and for this situation.

By the way, I'm a native french speaker, but not a professional linguist.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you just arrived to an appointment with some businessmen. You are expecting five persons to join the meeting but **no one is there yet**. A friend calls you to check on the meeting and asks you if the others arrived yet by saying `Les autres sont - ils arrivés?`. You can answer `personne n'est arrivé`which would be perfectly correct. But you would still be expecting them to show up anytime. So your statement:

> In French it would be Personne n'est arrivé which to me is something happened once and complete in the past

Is incomplete: it can be something that happened in the past but is still ongoing.

Now let's assume that **two years later** you are relating this event. You could say `Personne n'arrivait, et je m'impatientais.` It means that action happened once in the past and it is not continuing in the present, but still it is part of a sequence of actions that all occured in the past once (it could be followed for example by `...tout frustré je décidais de m'en aller`or a happier situation: `...enfin ils arrivèrent tous en trombe et s'excusèrent du retard`)

Comment: Sauf erreur "tout frustré je décidais de m'en aller" devrait plutôt être "tout frustré je décidai de m'en aller", avec un verbe au passé simple car une décision à priori ne dure pas dans le temps...