# Can the negators "jamais, rien, personne, plus, ni, aucun" be used in a single sentence?

Tags: grammaire, négation

I understand that when a sentence has a negative word like "jamais, rien, personne, plus, ni, aucun", you don't use "pas". But is it possible or normal to use three or four of them together in a single sentence, even if it may be impossible to use all them together? Is this type of construct with multiple negative words standard or should they be avoided?

Comment: In case you wished for a generic response rather than examples of sentences with a lot of negators, the rule is simply that "pas" isn't normally used when another negative adverb is (I've heard it happen a few times though) unless you want to negate your negation ("c'est pas rien") but that *they* can all co-occur with each other without restriction.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using all six of them, you can say, for instance:

- > **Rien ni personne** ne pourrait **plus jamais** me faire croire en **aucune** de ses belles paroles.
- > À partir de maintenant, je vais m'efforcer de ne **plus jamais rien** devoir à **personne** en **aucun** cas, **ni** dans ma vie personnelle **ni** dans ma vie professionnelle.

Practically speaking, it is not common to see five or six of them crammed together like this, but there is nothing grammatically wrong or unidiomatic about it.

Comment: For more examples, I remember giving a few in a [related question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7451). I was definitely way too conservative there :)

Comment: @Fólkvangr Par exemple, « *en aucun cas* » et « *jamais* » peuvent très bien s'employer ensemble, voire côte à côte, même si en temps normal on n'utilise que l'un ou l'autre dans une même proposition. La signification et l'usage de ces termes ne sont pas identiques.

Comment: Is it possible to shorten the second example to: À partir de maintenant, je vais m'efforcer de ne plus jamais rien devoir à personne en aucun cas dans ma vie ni personnelle ni professionnelle.

Comment: @Fólkvangr: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: @nalply In contrast to your phrasing that doesn't work, you can say: "*Je n'ai plus aucune ambition, **ni** professionnelle, **ni** amoureuse.*" without using the noun "*ambition*" twice. As for why your phrasing doesn't work, it is interpreted as: "*my life is neither personal nor professional*", "*my life with no personal or professional aspect*".

Answer (score 3):

> Jamais aucun, ni plus personne : rien.

Une phrase averbale, elliptique voire incomplète qui évoque davantage qu'elle n'explique. Une clé d'analyse pourrait être la formule « il n'y a » (LBU14 § 1030), vague mais utile (comme on pourrait sans doute y recourir pour analyser « Pas un seul petit morceau / De mouche ou de vermisseau », La Fontaine, *La Cigale et la Fourmi*). On évoque peut-être le passé, le présent, voire le futur, certainement l'absence d'êtres ou le néant. On aime bien, ce n'est pas nécessairement typique, on ne voit pas pourquoi on s'en passerait.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Il y a un certain mérite technique à ton commentaire intransigeant, mais il est incomplet, c'est possible d'avoir ça sans copule ni verbe sous-jacent facilement identifiable et il faut alors recourir à un support vague comme _il y a_ : _Pas un seul petit morceau / de mouche ou de vermisseau._ (La Fontaine). Je me réclame de ce genre de phrase. Ma réponse était plus un clin d’œil que d'autre chose, et on a déjà une réponse plus conventionnelle. Tu manques d'imagination à mon avis.

Answer (score 2):

> Jamais rien ni personne ne pourra plus m'empêcher de n'en choisir aucun.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je trouve ton commentaire très sévère d'autant plus que la variante que tu suggères change le sens de ma phrase sur deux points. 1. l'historique est perdu: avant on m'empêchait ne ne pas choisir, cette information a disparu, 2. rien ne dit qu'il ne fallait pas en choisir plusieurs, auquel cas *en choisir un* serait un contresens.

Comment: @Fólkvangr C'est bien le sens attendu. J'ai tout de même la sensation que, peut-être contrarié par un -1 reçu, tu as décidé d'accorder le même sort à toutes les autres réponses à cette question, ce qui est cependant ton droit le plus absolu...

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je ne comprends pas ta dernière phrase. En quoi le fait pour des termes de dériver de quelque chose, ce qui est pourtant assez inné pour eux, rendrait les expressions construites avec insatisfaisantes ?

Answer (score 1):

`"Tu ne posséderas jamais plus aucun tricycle"`. Here `"jamais plus"` express the fact that not even one more is acceptable and `"aucun"` may be interpreted as referring to quantity. 
So yes you could see three of them but they would not all express negation at that time.

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that *plus* have different meaning. "*J'en veux plus*" et "*Je n'en veux plus*" don't mean the same thing (I want more, I don't want it anymore).

So the sentence "*Je ne veux rien (de) plus*" use 2 of those words but only *rien* has a negative meaning.

There is different sentence that mix them: *rien ni personne*, *plus jamais*, *jamais rien*.

*Il n'y aura **plus jamais rien ni personne** sur cette planète* is a valid sentence.
*Plus jamais rien ni aucune personne* is also valid but here personne refer to the noun (people) instead of the negative word (no one)

Comment: @Fólkvangr no. *rien ni personne* is an idiom:  [linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/rien+ni+personne.html)

Comment: @Fólkvangr I agree that in this context it's not the best example but it's not incorrect

Comment: In informal style "J'en veux plus" et "Je n'en veux plus" do mean the same thing if you pronounce  "plus" like "plu". Anyway, you always pronounce "plus" like  "plu" in "Je n'en veux plus".

Comment: @LPH yeah I didn't mention the tone since it's not the subject of the question but good remark

Answer (score 1):

There are possibilities in which, on top of the 6  words considered, "ne" can be added; here is one;

- Plus jamais personne ni rien n'était désagréable à aucun.

However, there'll be often better ways to formulate such satements so as to make them more direct and so more readily understandable; in the case of the sentence above, the  phrasing given below will often be found preferable, but it is longer;

- Depuis ce temps-là il y avait toujours quelqu'un pour trouver  quelqu'un ou quelque chose de désagréable.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je crois que c'est correct grammaticalement; « Personne  n'était désagréable à aucun. » est correct; est aussi correct « Rien n'était désagréable à aucun. » ; on peut donc combiner avec la conjonction de coordination: « Personne  n'était désagréable à aucun, ni rien n'était désagréable à aucun. » ; en simplifiant cela donne « Personne ni rien  n'était désagréable à aucun. » (« ni » signifie « et ».) L'ajout du complément circonstanciel de temps « Plus jamais » ne présente aucun problème. Je crois aussi que l'équivalence signifie quelque chose de sensé et qu'elle correspond.